# killing linkedin session after user passes through my application

Tags: php, linkedin-api

I have an app that i use at networking events where users walkup and accept it. It seems that linkedin keeps the user logged in when i pass them through the "accept application" dialog.

Anyone know how to log the user out using code? As this would save me closing the browser everytime to kill the session, which slows down the process greatly.

Comment: Short version: Are you using REST or JS API?  Your question doesn't quite make sense (to me). It's keeping the session alive in the server-side REST requests, or it's keeping it active in the browser? If it's the latter, are you using the javascript api to authenticate the user? If so, the question should be tagged javascript, not php.

Comment: i am using the rest api- when i pass someone through the /uas/oauth/authorize?oauth_token then remain logged in when the next user goes to accept the application

Comment: So the oauth_token portal still shows the previous user? Crazy. Probably still similar fix as my answer, but let me double check.

Comment: Are you requesting a new OAuth token (the one that you pass to the auth service) each time? If so, is it different each time?

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing everything server-side via PHP, then you don't need to kill that session, since it's only tied to the token. You just need to request a new token when the next user logs in. If you feel it's more secure, you could just set the token to `""` at the end.

If you are doing client-side authentication via Javascript API, then check out:

[IN.Auth, IN.Event, and IN.UI](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/inauth-inevent-and-inui)

Specifically, the section titled **"Log the User Out"**

It appears you just need to call the `logout` method, specifically:

```
IN.User.logout(callbackFunction, callbackScope)
```

Where callbackFunction is a function you define that gets called after the session ends, and callbackScope is an optional object that you want to run the callback function on (defaults to the `window` object).

It also mentions that running the above simply clears the cookies for the session, so hypothetically, if the above didn't fit, you could write a browser-based (which is to say, not running on the domain-restricted page, but in a browser add-on that has full access to all domain cookies) that deletes the cookies when the user reaches a certain page (maybe the thank you page?)

I imagine that would be overkill, however.

#### Update:

Based on some further reading of how the javascript API works (specifically how the API key that your app has for every request), it looks like the cookie that controls the user's session is tied to your domain, not linkedin (although this is odd, since linkedin shouldn't have access to your domains cookies to confirm that the session is still valid). I'd still use their build in method, but you could also kill the session by clearing whatever cookie they create through your own function.

Comment: hmmmm... will need to look at the cookies then